# Showing that a bundle homomorphism is a smooth isomorphism.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

This is Lee's problem $10-11$ in his *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*. If $\pi:E\to M$ and $\pi':E'\to M$ are vector bundles over the smooth manifold $M$ and if $F:E\to E'$ is a bijective smooth bundle homomorphism, then $F$ is a smooth bundle isomorphism. Here is my attempt. My question is at the very end.

We need to show that $F^{-1}$ is smooth. So, let $p\in E.$ There are open sets $U,U'\subseteq M$ such that $p\in U, F(p)\in U'$ and such that there are local trivializations $\Psi:\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \mathbb R^n\ $ and $\Psi':\pi'^{-1}(U')\to U'\times \mathbb R^n.$ Define $f=\Psi'\circ F\circ \Psi^{-1}$ on a sufficiently small open set containing $\Psi (p)$ so that the diagram from which the following data follow makes sense:

$\tag 1 \pi_U\circ \Psi=\pi$

$\tag 2 \pi_{U'}\circ \Psi'=\pi'$

$\tag 3 \pi'\circ F=\pi$

Now, take $x\times v$ in this open set. Using $(1),(2),(3),$ we can show that $f$ sends $x\times v$ to $x\times w$ for some $w\in \mathbb R^n.$ Since $\Psi, \Psi'$ are diffeomorphisms and and $F$ is bijective, $f$ is bijective. We also have that $f\big |_{ \{x\}\times \mathbb R^n}$ is a vector space isomorphism. This means that there is an invertible linear transformation $\tau_x:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^n$ such that $f(x,v)=(x,\tau_x(v)).$ Then, $f^{-1}(x,v)=(x,\tau_x^{-1}(v)).$ To finish, just note that $f^{-1}=\Psi\circ F^{-1}\circ \Psi'^{-1}$ and  that the composition $(x,v)\mapsto (x,\tau_x(v))\mapsto (x,\tau_x^{-1}(v))$ is smooth. Inversion is smooth but it is not clear to me why the first one is.

Edit: the first map is smooth just because it is just $f=\Psi'\circ F\circ \Psi^{-1},$ which is smooth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be clear, the first map is smooth because it is just $F$ in local trivializations. The main issue is to know that $x\mapsto \tau_x$ is smooth, the argument for which I sketch here.

After choosing local frames for the source and the target, say $\{e_j\}$ for the source and $\{f_i\}$ for the target, write $$\tau_x(v) = \tau_x(v^je_j) = v^j\tau_x(e_j) = v^j(\tau_x)_j^if_i.$$ So to prove $x\mapsto \tau_x$ is smooth, all we need is to justify that each of the functions $x\mapsto (\tau_x)^i_j$ is smooth. How can you express $(\tau_x)^i_j$ as a composition of smooth functions using the data $\{e_j\}$, $\{f_i\}$, and $\tau_x$?

*Hint.* Pick a dual co-frame for $\{f_i\}$.

Comment: Yes, indeed, Happy to upvote. But I really made much too much of this. The first map is smooth just because it is $f=\Psi'\circ F\circ \Psi^{-1}$ which is smooth.

Comment: @Matematleta: I think the point of the exercise comes down to knowing that the inverse of the given bundle homomorphism in local trivializations looks like $(x,\tau_x^{-1}v)$, where the bundle homomorphism itself in the trivializations is $(x,\tau_xv)$, and then picking your favorite proof that $\tau_x^{-1}$ is smooth if $\tau_x$ is smooth, say by using Cramer's rule. Of course, it is not a part of the definition of a bundle homomorphism in Lee that $\tau_x$ be smooth as a function of $x$, so this answer addresses the more pressing issue of proving that $x\mapsto \tau_x$ is smooth.

Comment: @Matematleta just to be clear: the smoothness of the first map is trivial because it is just $f$. The "non-trivial" part of your question is showing that $x\mapsto \tau_x$ is smooth as a mapping of an open set in $\Bbb{R}^{\dim M}$ into some $\text{Hom}$ space (which you can do by reading this answer in reverse). Then, knowing that inversion is smooth, you can conclude that $(x,v)\mapsto (\tau_x)^{-1}\cdot v = (\text{inv}\circ \tau)(x)\cdot v$ is smooth.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Yes, to your first comment. I edited my question as soon as I realized that I had forgotten that $F$ is assumed smooth, not just bijective and inear on fibers. As to you second comment, this is also an exercise in Lee's book, which I was able to do.

Comment: @AlexOrtiz and peek-a.-boo: a  shorter way?  We know that $f$ is smooth and $f(x,v)=(x,\tau_x(v)).$ Therefore, $p_2\circ f(x,v)=\tau_x(v)$ is smooth. So, with $\{e_i\}$ the standard basis, we have that the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix representation of $\tau_x$ is $\pi_i(\tau_x(e_j))=\pi_i\circ p_2(f(x,e_j)),$ which is smooth.